# Is it possible to fetch specific Firebase Remote Config settings in reaction to user behavior?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

Is it possible to fetch a specific set of Firebase Remote Config parameters based on user input or behavior? Suppose we ask a user to input their favorite color and then we want to provide a Remote Config tailored to users who put in that color, is there any way to do that?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
val settings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
  .setString(USER_FAVORITE_COLOR, editTextFavoriteColor.text)
  .build()

firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(settings)
firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch()
  .addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
      firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched()
      textViewGreeting.text = "Hello, fellow 
      ${firebaseRemoteConfig.getString(BACKGROUND_COLOR)} lover"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a coworker's help we were able to figure this out!

```
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty(USER_FAVORITE_COLOR, favoriteColor)
firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(remoteConfigFetchListener)
```

It even happens immediately! By the time remoteConfigFetchListener gets called the Remote Config values we can `activateFetched()` with are the ones that we configured in the Firebase Remote Config web console. :D